# Wi-Fi connections, 2

Tags: wireless

Let me add some information to my question.  I have Ubuntu 20.4 on a laptop used as a desk computer (the laptop is a fairly old Lenovo E545).  If I start the laptop in a motel room, I want it to look for all the Wi-Fi signals it can find and allow me to choose among them for my connection.  How do I tell it to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu already does this...

1. Click on the set of icons at the right side of the the top bar.

   [image]
2. Click "Wi-Fi Not Connected" to expand it, and click "Select Network"

   [image]
3. From the pop-up dialog, select the network you want to connect to and click the "Connect" button.

   [image]
4. Finally, enter your WIFI password when prompted.

If you need to connect to a captive portal (like a hotel wifi), your web browser should open. If it does not open, you can open your web browser and try to navigate to a site, and you should be prompted to enter your guest credentials.

---

As an alternative to clicking on the set of icons at the right side of the the top bar, you can also open the "System Settings" app and click on "Wi-Fi" in the left panel to see a list of available wireless networks.